# RouteTable in Asp.Net Core 6.0

Tags: routetable

I'm new to Asp.Net Core. I wanted to use `RouteTable` in.NET Core 6.0 to remove routes, but it seems to have removed this feature. Can anyone tell me what's the alternative.